# How to setup a Doctrine test to have automatic rollback of the transaction (to avoid dirtying db)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I would like to have tests dealing with Doctrine not persist stuff in the main Symfony dev database. Preferably by not storing stuff at all (rolling back per test). How would I do this? Are there ready-made frameworks/libs/setups I can use?

At work we have a really smooth working Java setup where database tests extends custom JUnit test classes we have created. `TransactionallyIsolatedITest` for running everything within a transaction that is rolled back (fast), `FullyIsolatedITest` for testing stuff that do their own `begin()`, `commit()`, stuff, etc. This creates and tears down a database created from a template for each test (heavy/slow).

Having something like this would be beautful when doing Symfony development in PHP.

Comment: Yes, there is at [least one](https://packagist.org/packages/dama/doctrine-test-bundle), and if you happen to be using [alice](https://packagist.org/packages/hautelook/alice-bundle) it has [several helpers](https://github.com/theofidry/AliceBundle/tree/master/src/PhpUnit) too. I'd use a different environment for the tests, though. If you are dead set on cloning your database, you could do that while bootstraping `phpunit`.

Comment: In Symfony you can have multiple env. So you can override your database config and use a totally different db. Just be sure to regenerate your shema on your env.

Comment: The hint on the downvote button should tell you part of the story: "The question does not show research effort". Which is kind of a big thing as per the [ask] page and shouldn't have been too hard with a search on packagist. Also, you explicitly ask for a library, which goes against a SO guideline and is a close-vote reason. I'd expect someone with your reputation to already know this.

Comment: @msg Thanks, that's fair. I'm new to the PHP world and actually didn't know about packagist after well over a year  Also, sometimes the hardest thing is coming up with the right search terms (I obviously didn't), since I only asked after  searching fruitlessly 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Symfony 6 documentation they actually [describe and show how](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test) to reset the database before every test using the [DAMADoctrineTestBundle](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle).

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the `setUp` method,
inside that you can get the enityManager instance like this `$em = self::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();`
and then purge the database via the Doctrine ORM purger

```
$purger = new Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger($em);
$purger->purge();
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to just do `DROP` and `CREATE` on most tables, which is a bit inelegant and heavy-handed. It would also destroy whatever dev data I would have in the database at that point. Can I dynamically reconfigure doctrine at runtime to clone and use another database?

Comment: You should then use a configuration for the test environment [Symfony Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#set-up-your-test-environment) and name it `doctrine.yaml`. And in there specify the DB connection to a sqlite local file. You can then delete the data all you want because it won't mess with your dev DB.

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/test.db'
`